# shopify api can not get all products I get undefined all

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-api-node

I use the shopify api nodejs and all works fine and I can login and auth.

I also get the access token and the session.

Now I want to get all products but I got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'all')
    at C:\express_inngest\src\server.ts:127:47
    at step (C:\express_inngest\src\server.ts:56:23)
    at Object.next (C:\express_inngest\src\server.ts:37:53)
    at fulfilled (C:\express_inngest\src\server.ts:28:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

here is my code:

```
app.get('/auth/callback', async (req: any, res: any) => {
  try {
  // The library will automatically redirect the user
  console.log('CALLBACK');
  const callback = await shopify.auth.callback({
    rawRequest: req,
    rawResponse: res,
  });

  const response = await shopify.webhooks.register({
    session: callback.session,
  });

  const products = await shopify.rest.Product.all({
    session: callback.session,
  });

  if (!response['PRODUCTS_CREATE'][0]?.success) {
    Sentry.captureException(
      `Failed to register PRODUCTS_CREATE webhook: ${response['PRODUCTS_CREATE'][0]?.result}`,
    );
  }
  
  res.send('AUTH');
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
    Sentry.captureException(e);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, the problem is the `restResources` is missing in shopifyApi declaration. In my case, to fix that, I set my shopifyApi like :

```js
const shopify = shopifyApi({
  apiKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_KEY,
  apiSecretKey: process.env.SHOPIFY_API_SECRET ?? "",
  scopes: process.env.SCOPES?.split(","),
  hostName: process.env.SHOPIFY_APP_URL?.replace(/https:\/\//, "") ?? "",
  apiVersion: ApiVersion.April23,
  isEmbeddedApp: true,
  restResources: restResources, // I add this line
});
```

And I import my ressource from :

```js
import { restResources } from "@shopify/shopify-api/rest/admin/2023-10";
```